# MEW says not a valid erc20 token but don't see errors

Tags: ether, tokens, erc-20

I created a token prior to this one that is fine. I used the same template, followed the same exact steps to create another token but getting the not valid erc20 error.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x43e04ca6a9ce3556bfeb4a7e34da9828a65d073d#code

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: Checking the same on MyCrypto.com it shows I have 3,000,000 HDM in the Ropsten network, but 0 in the Ethereum mainnet. Shouldn't that be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is MEW complaining about but take a look at [EIP20 on github](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md). Function declarations are a bit different than the ones on theethereum.wiki which probably you used in your token implementation.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually used this templae (which, as I stated, I used before to create another token which has no issues: https://github.com/bitfwdcommunity/Issue-your-own-ERC20-token/blob/master/contracts/erc20_tutorial.sol

Comment: My assumption is that they improved MEW code validator (if there is such a thing) to follow a bit newer standard improvements. Pay attention whose template you are using cause everyone is writing code these days and just copy/paste-ing. Not saying that template you have used is bad, but the link I provided in answer is from ethereum repo so you might think about upgrading your template although the one you use used to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay issue resolved. I simply deployed again but this time on the mainnet and they are now showing up. Weird that I didn't have to do that step last time, but, all's well that ends well :)